# How to reformat a text file data formatting in python (reading a csv/txt with multiple delimiters and rows)

Tags: python, dataframe, parsing

Coding noob here with a question. I have a text file that has the following format:

img1.jpg 468,3,489,16,5 510,37,533,51,2 411,3,433,17,5 ....

img2.jpg 255,397,267,417,2 ....
.
.
.

The data is a series of images with information on co-ordinates where there are 5 variables separated by commas, and then a new set of co-ordinates is separated by a space. There are about 500 files and for each file there are variable numbers of co-ordinate groups. I'm wanting to convert this text file into the following kind of format:

| File name | Co-ord 1 | Co-ord 2 | Co-ord 3 | Co-ord 4 | Co-ord 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| img1.jpg | 468 | 3 | 489 | 16 | 5 |
| img1.jpg | 510 | 37 | 533 | 51 | 2 |
| img1.jpg | 411 | 3 | 433 | 17 | 5 |
| img2.jpg | 255 | 397 | 267 | 417 | 2 |

How can I do this in python?

Comment: the file is one line or it is multiple rows? not clear from your post

Comment: the file has multiple rows (each row is info for a new image file). there are about 500 images (i.e. 500 rows) in total (I tried to update the formatting in the post)

Comment: By writing some code. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Since each image name and group of co-ordinates are separated by spaces, we can use *split()* to split it info array and it's basically what your expected output.
Here i wrote an example that split your input into a list of lists, each inner list represent one line in your example output with the first element describe which image the co-ordinates belong to:

```
test = "img1.jpg 468,3,489,16,5 510,37,533,51,2 411,3,433,17,5"
str_list = test.split()
res = list()
recent_img = ''
for item in str_list:
    if item.endswith("jpg"):
        # find a new image name
        recent_img = item
        continue
    co_ordinates_list = item.split(",")
    if len(co_ordinates_list) == 5:
        co_ordinates_list.insert(0, recent_img)
        res.append(co_ordinates_list)
```